# Cacti Graph does not show actual value for  outbound

Tags: ubuntu, cacti

I have configured cacti on Ubuntu and added a switch as a host. I want to monitor each port of this switch. I have created graphs for that host and have not edited any graph template settings. When I explored graph for a specific port, it does not show actual outbound value. For example if current outbound is 300Mbps, it shows 79Mbps. What should I do??

If you need any additional information, please add comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind Cacti samples periodically so you'll get an average on the graph.

I suspect the problem however is down to the counter used when you created the graph. For gigabit interfaces you need 64bit counters eg: `In/Out bits (64 bit counters)`, otherwise the counter will overflow due to the rate of the interface and you'll get weird results like you're seeing.